# Text file with column to odbc database

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access, odbc

I daily get logs in text file format. After I run notepad++ macro to clean the file(junk lines and empty/blank lines)/

I imported it in access table and from there I exported to odbc database some how I don't know.

After making the odbc access connection I use access odbc connection to do my sql query and create a needed report.

Is there a way I can automate this process? to update access database from daily text log I get?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention ODBC and Access, I assume you are on Windows. What you are asking for can be done using Windows Script. Scripts may be written in either VBScript or JScript. Using ActiveX objects, it is relatively simple to establish a connection to either Access or an ODBC source or both. As for reading and manipulating a log file, depending on the size of the file you should be able to load the contents of the file and go to town with regular expressions to clean it up or extract any data you need.

Windows Script Host: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host

ADO Connection (for database connectivity): http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_connection.asp

Connection Strings for Access Database: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Further, you mention generating reports. Anything you can do as a macro in Access can also be done from within a script. You could call Access from your script and have reports generate and even print automatically, if you want.

Access Application Object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa199147%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already done half of what you mentioned, thanks for sharing your method looks like solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could automate it by moving your logic to different places.  My approach would be to write a ColdFusion (.net, java, etc would also be ok, I think) application that reads the file.  It could then do the stuff you now do it Notepad++.  Then, it would populate a staging table in the odbc database, and update the real table from the staging table.

Then I would schedule by application to run at the desired interval.

Some databases have bulk loading utilities that can also be used.